# i don't understand how length() works in this code

Tags: java

Can someone please explain this code for me, especially this part.

```
int lastpos = message.length() - 1;
```

Why did he add - 1 ?

==

```
    System.out.print("What is your message? ");
    String message = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nYour message is " + message.length() + " characters long.");
    System.out.println("The first character is at position 0 and is '" + message.charAt(0) + "'.");
    int lastpos = message.length() - 1;
    System.out.println("The last character is at position " + lastpos + " and is '" + message.charAt(lastpos) + "'.");
    System.out.println("\nHere are all the characters, one at a time:\n");

    for ( int i=0; i < message.length(); i++ )
    {
        System.out.println("\t" + i + " - '" + message.charAt(i) + "'");
    }

    int a_count = 0;

    for ( int i=0; i<message.length(); i++ )
    {
        char letter = message.charAt(i);
        if ( letter == 'a' || letter == 'A' )
        {
            a_count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nYour message contains the letter 'a' " + a_count + " times. Isn't that interesting?");

}
```

}

Comment: You should explain a bit more what your problem is. To me it seems unclear what you mean with "Why did he add -1?". What do you mean with "he"? What addition do you mean? What should the code do?

Comment: Maybe he considered a statement/message which ends with a punctuation and he expects to avoid that. But that's bit parky. A conditional check at that point would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a String "Abdullah" and you want to print last character of that string then 
`int lastpos = message.length() - 1`
Iine gives you last character of that String.
So in given code that line print the last character of the input String.

Answer (score 2):

Because indices start at 0 . If you have a list of `{0, 1, 2}`, note that it has a length of 3, but the last index is only 2. `- 1` is used to correct for that.

If you iterated to the element at index `3` (the length of the list), you would go off the end of the list, causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Note, I used lists as an example for ease of understanding, but it's exactly the same when it comes to Strings. All iterables start at an index of 0.

Comment: length() function in java returns the exact number of characters in a string. The question above works with Strings only. Please clarify.

Comment: @BiswajitR It's exactly the same for strings and lists. I'll update the terminology in a bit.